# OpenGL redraw different render results for identical parameter

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have a strange problem which I guess gets caused by qt.
I'm using the qt OpenGL widget and my redraw routine and the MouseMove event look like this:

```
void RenderGraphFrame::redraw()
{
    GLdouble objX, objY, objZ;
    GLdouble ModelViewMatrixvector[16], ProjectionViewMatrixVector[16];
    GLint ViewportVector[4];

    glGetIntegerv (GL_VIEWPORT, ViewportVector);
    glGetDoublev (GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ModelViewMatrixvector);
    glGetDoublev (GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, ProjectionViewMatrixVector);

    gluUnProject(mousepositionX, mousepositionY, 0,
                 ModelViewMatrixvector,
                 ProjectionViewMatrixVector,
                 ViewportVector,
                 &objX,  &objY, &objZ);

    qDebug() << "objX: " << objX << " objY: " << objY << " objZ: " << objZ;

    qglColor(Qt::red);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glNormal3f(0,-1,0.707);
        glVertex3f(objX-1,objY-1,0);
        glVertex3f(objX+1,objY-1,0);
        glVertex3f(objX,objY,1.2);
    glEnd();
}

void RenderGraphFrame::mouseMoveEvent (QMouseEvent *event)
{
    mousepositionX = event->x();
    mousepositionY = event->y();
    redraw();
    return;
}
```

When I'm moving the mouse over the widget I get a whole stream of output through `qDebug()` so it is sure the Even triggers and `redraw()` gets executed.

For testing I want a sqaure consiting of 4 triangles to be rendered where 1 of them follows the cursor.

But there are only 3 shapes the 4th is missing... Thats at least what I was thinking. While I was dbeugging I figgured out while I was alt+tabbing out of the window, that when I'm pressing the `alt`-key the `redraw()`method gets invoked again with exactly the same output of the last mouse move but now the 4th shape gets rendered (not on the position I want, but that is probabbly just error in my 3d-logic)

How can that be?
Is there anything mysterious what is qt doing in the widget that causes this? And if it is not my fault, what can I do that qt lets me do as it is desired?

**edit:**

-I noticed that just pressing the `alt`-key to to cause a desired rendering is hard to reproduce (tabbing into other applicantions while clicking on different on the alt+tab menu some times work). But what is reproducable is:
When I tab out of the application and then tab in again, the redraw works as it should. But not while invoked from the mousemove event.

-I deleted the static shapes which are not the problem, so the code is more easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is to assume that the OpenGL context is in the same state at each function call. However, Qt modifies a lot of states while rendering its own stuff. That is why you get different results even when you do exactly the same GL calls in your code every time.

Quoting the Qt documentation:

> [...] the state of the current OpenGL context will be altered by the paint engine to reflect its needs. Applications should not rely upon the OpenGL state being reset to its original conditions, particularly the current shader program, OpenGL viewport, texture units, and drawing modes.

So, a lot of states like bound textures, polygon mode, blending, depth tests, etc. are basically in a random state every time `redraw()` is called. You have to reset all of them at the beginning of `redraw()` to make sure you get the same result every time.

Comment: +1 so far because ti sounds logical to me. But before I accept this, I would like to see a solution or a explanation how to implement that reset.

Comment: In your specific scenario, I would take a look at the viewport and matrix values, and see if these are in a sane state. You are currently using them for your unprojection, but Qt might have set them to incorrect values and you might have to reset them. You can use [apitrace](http://apitrace.github.io/) to see what exactly Qt is doing and which states you need to reset.

Comment: But I'm logging the values returned from gluUnProject, which is relying on the matrices. So their output should be different between correct and incorrect behaving, shouldn't it? As currently in both cases gluUnProject output is the same. But I'll look in.

Comment: I fixed the problem: I had to use `updateGL();` instead of invoking the redraw method. I'll provide a own answer. But If you can explain it better than Mine will be(edited into your answer), I'll still tend to accept your answer.

Comment: No, go ahead and post your own answer, seems like I was wrong then.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this behaving by changing in the event listener the method call of `redraw()` to `updateGL()`. This acts probably in respect to own acting of qt, as described by Lukas Boersma in his answer.

the now as intended running version has this implementation of the method:

```
void RenderGraphFrame::mouseMoveEvent (QMouseEvent *event)
{
    mousepositionX = event->x();
    mousepositionY = event->y();
    updateGL();
    return;
}
```

note:
`updateGL()` is an external function!